# Enable AWS VPC Flow Logs with Ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

When creating an AWS VPC with Ansible, how to enable [VPC Flow Logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/flow-logs.html)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do this directly with any of the officially released Ansible modules, but - as with anything that Ansible doesn't directly support - you can just [shell](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/shell_module.html) out instead.

So if you wanted to enable VPC flow logs you could use the AWS CLI's [`create-flow-logs`](http://create-flow-logs) command:

```
- name: enable vpc flow logs
  local_action: shell aws ec2 create-flow-logs --resource-type VPC --resource-ids {{ vpc_id }} --traffic-type ALL --log-group-name {{ vpc_flow_log_group_name }} --deliver-logs-permission-arn {{ vpc_flow_log_iam_role_arn }}
```

In addition to that, if ansible supports hooks or custom resource triggering, you can also enable VPC flow logs through the CloudFormation or even better using [CDK](https://aws.amazon.com/cdk/?nc1=h_ls). For more information refer to [official doc](https://aws.amazon.com/ru/about-aws/whats-new/2016/06/aws-cloudformation-adds-support-for-amazon-vpc-flow-logs-amazon-kinesis-firehose-streams-and-other-updates/)

Comment: Still checking with ansible for community module support.

Comment: Still no dice @ 9-18-2017 :(